# Android Camera: getPhysicalCameraIds is not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, android-9.0-pie

I was trying to add support for fused camera streams in a project I'm working on and I tried querying for support. However, the new methods like `getPhysicalCameraIds()` or constants like `REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA` are not found and thus compilation fails.

I have `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` set to 28. I've also made sure I have the Android P SDK installed... and restarted Android Studio, but no luck.

Is there anything else I need to configure?

Comment: Are you working with the Emulator?

Comment: No, I’m building without emulator or device (tried it with an Android 9 device as well, no luck.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your complaint. For me, this works. Try the following test: add in your code `int qqq = CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED`, make sure to `import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata`, put your mouse over the value and *Go To Declaration*. I expect it to be *C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/sources/android-28/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.java*, and in that java file I can see REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_LOGICAL_MULTI_CAMERA declared.

Comment: I looked into the sources of CameraCharacteristics which should expose `getPhysicalCameraIds` but it doesn’t. I’m thinking this must be some Android Studio bug, as I checked and double checked to have the Android 9 sdk fully installed, yet the sources don’t seem to reflect that. I’ve also had a look in Build.VERSION_CODES and there’s no mention of Android P... just O.

Comment: The file path should give you a hint. Mine has `sources/android-28/`. One trick is to click *File | Invalidate Caches/Restart* menu.

Comment: Invalidate Caches/Restart fixed it. Please add this as an answer.